# Disable or Force Close Mobile Keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, sap-fiori, soft-keyboard

I have deployed my **UI5** project in **Fiori** Launchpad (Fiori Client) with mobile Barcode Scanner (Zebra TC20). We are using input to capture the barcode value in the application. When we focus on input field by default soft keyboard of mobile device opens. Please give me some suggestion how to disable the soft keyboard in mobile device.

[Fiori Mobile Disable Keyboard Input](https://answers.sap.com/questions/757261/fiori-mobile-disable-keyboard-input.html?childToView=762822)

```
_focusEannr: function() {
            var oEan11 = this.byId("iEan11");

        oEan11.addEventDelegate({

            onfocusin: function(e) {
                try {
                debugger;
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    blur();
                } catch (err) {
                    alert(err.toString());
                }
            },
            onfocus: function(oEvent) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: is it phonegap/cordova based on only javascript

Comment: How does the bar code scanner interact with the input field? Is another app launched once the user clicks the input field or how does it get opened?

Comment: hi Jorg not cordova aplication. Web applicaton it display at webviever

Comment: Hi  corschdi user push input aftering focus cursor set on the input field. After user push barcode read buton scanner fill input which cursor setted input.

Answer (score 0):

Make the input field *read-only* by setting `editable="false"`

```xml
<Input value="{myBinding}" editable="false" />
```

[image: ui5 non-editable input field]

> *editable:* Defines whether the control can be modified by the user or not. **Note:** A user can tab to non-editable control, highlight it, and copy the text from it.

[API reference: `sap.m.InputBase#setEditable`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/methods/setEditable)

---

Alternatively, you can close soft keyboard manually with the following method:

```js
sap.ui.require(["sap/m/library"], sapMLib => sapMLib.closeKeyboard());
```

[API reference: `sap.m.closeKeyboard`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m/methods/sap.m.closeKeyboard)

Comment: Thanks , I try this code it's work but  close keyboad method have blur method so this code close poınter,(out of focus ) barcode scanner not fill input.